# Number of addition and multiplication operators in this algorithm

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

Consider the following algorithm:

```
i := 1
t := 0
    while i ≤ n
       t := t + i
       i := 2i
```

I'm interested in finding out how many addition and multiplication operations this algorithm executes; however, I'm running into trouble.  I understand that the value of i doubles after each iteration, but I don't know how to generalize the algorithm to give a correct number of operations up until the value of n.  If anyone can shed some light on the issue, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Each loop contains one addition and one multiplication, so you just have to figure out how many times the loop runs.

Comment: I understand this.  However, I'm having trouble at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of `i` doubles every loop and `i <= n`

```
i*2^x <= n
```

and maximizing x gives the number of loops. Since i = 1

```
2^x = n
x = floor log(n)
```

and we perform 1 addition and 1 multiplication per loop. I think you can take it from here :)

Comment: Can you explain how you got the term 2^x?

Comment: The number of loops execute

Comment: OH (No pun intended)! I was misinterpreting the problem (as well as your response). Thanks for the help, really appreciate it :D

Comment: No problem, if my answer is good then please check the little green check beside it to mark this question as answered

Comment: In one minute, I will! You little handsome booger :P <3